# Rebuilding kernel modules and replacing the .ko file causes the kernel not the boot

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I rebuilt `xr_usb_serial_common` (changed USB support from 32 devices to 64) and placed the newly complied `xr_usb_serial_common.ko` in `/lib/modules/5.4.0-80-generic/kernel/ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/` but when I rebooted the kernel was unable to boot.

I replaced the original `xr_usb_serial_common.ko` in the location and kernel booted fine.

What am I missing here?